# Does C standardize the linker symbol naming?

Tags: c, x86, x86-64

When I look at symbols that my Visual C++ linker creates for C functions, it always start with underline. For example symbol of `int example(int)` is in form `_example`.

I was wondering if this is specified in the C standard? If not, then I wonder is this specified by any C ABI for x86/x64?

I'm hoping that someone could enlighten me a bit there.

EDIT: Reason why I'm interested about this is that I've seen that the underline prefix is pretty common at least under x86 platforms. It felt weird that this would be coincident, so I'm wondering if some Intel x86 ABI or such is defining this?

Comment: No, it's not specified by the Standard. The Standard doesn't even know about the concept of a "binary" or "executable". Typically, this is something that a particular **compiler** mandates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As H2CO3 said it is not specified by the standard, however there are certain calling conventions which are more or less consistent on a specific platform. For X86 there is a decent article in the [x86 Disassembly Wikibook: Calling Conventions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions), however these are not regulated by a standard (it even say that the compiler "often" decorates the function names and that you should always check how a specific compiler implements the calling convention).

Comment: Thanks, this cleared it up pretty much. I've been familar with the calling conventions, but I had no idea that they do some name mangling.